# using Ffmpeg create fast, maintain quality and compress video(Mp4).I need convert more fast and best quality with compressed

Tags: ffmpeg

I need help to convert lasrge size of Mp4 file in compressed and maintaine quality with fast conversion speed.

I have a Mp4 file whose size is 235 MB but i need to compress and maintain quality  and convert without taking too much time.

But when i use this command to create that all thing they are taking 4 to 5 min time and quality is very low whereas the size is compressed (It becomes 32 Mb).
So, can any one help me to perform this operation.

```
   1).  "-i 503148_inn.mp4 -codec:a copy -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 503148.mp4"

   2).  "-i 503148_inn.mp4 -codec:a copy -preset ultrafast -vcodec h264 -b:v 
       1000k -acodec mp3 503148.mp4"
```

whereas i am sending the file URL where you all are download and test the file. 
     https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GMyHHpz5QOzDM0rNBGHkiz_mw4OE-0LD/view? 
     usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

“Fast, Small, high quality”. What you are looking for does not exist. You will always need to prioritize one of these elements over the others.

Comment: then our main priority is fast and compress

Comment: Use the slowest `-preset` you have patience for. Use the highest `-crf` value that provides an acceptable quality. Stream copy AAC audio instead of re-encoding it.

Comment: then as per your suggestion what is the complete command line?